# how to correctly setup credential-osxkeychain for git

Tags: macos, git, keychain

I have followed the instructions on [how to set up git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) to integrate the OS X keychain to the git command. The instructions say that the password prompt should come up once more, and that the keychain access window will come up. the password prompt up, but the keychain window did not. Also, subsequent commands requiring authentication (to a `https://` url) came up with a password prompt. None of these commands raised any kind of error or warning that something went foul.

My question is how can i get the git command to use the keychain for `https://` requests, so that I dont have to retype my username and password?

Some useful command output follows:

```
$ ls $(dirname $(which git)) | grep git
git
git-credential-osxkeychain
git-cvsserver
git-receive-pack
git-shell
git-upload-archive
git-upload-pack
gitk
$ git credential-osxkeychain
Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
$ git config --global credential.helper
osxkeychain
$ uname -a
Darwin mac-alex 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ git --version
git version 1.7.5.4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a newer version of Git.  The credential helpers aren't supported until Git 1.7.10.

Comment: Right, 1.7.5.4 < 1.7.10 and doesn't have credential helper support. :-)  You need to get a newer version of Git.  Head over to [the Git webiste](http://git-scm.com) and grab the latest version.  Then you should be good.